# What is the difference between Atom and Neatbeans?

Tags: netbeans, atom-editor

I've been working with netbeans for 6 months, but it doesn't seems to be very popular for web development (for example PHP), still I find that is a very good and complete tool. Someone told me to try Atom (which is very popular), because of esthetic and efficiency in therms of using what you actually need.

Do you think that Neatbeans is outdated compare to Atom?

Is there any important reason to change from an IDE to an Editor for web development on php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans is a full-featured IDE where you can e.g debug, Atom is - as you already wrote - a rich text editor, which is extendable with plugins (maybe also to debug PHP, but I really don’t know), I’m also not aware if Atom supports code completion, but in general I would say use what you like, I’m a Java developer and I do not want to miss NetBeans a single day, I also used it for PHP development and it’s also not bad, but if you fine working with Atom, than go with Atom, otherwise stay with NetBeans or discover other tools like IntelliJ Webstorm or Brackets. I think noone can give you a concrete answer to your question, sorry.